# Keep an image of Heap and come back to it after executing some methods

Tags: java, jvm, stack

I have a situation where I want to instrument Java code to add function calls, those function I add calls to might affect the objects status in the system thus changing the state of the program. I am looking for a way to insert those calls but leave the program status unchanged.

I am looking for a method to store the status (Image?) of the heap and come back to it later, I mean at the end of my instrumentation code. I tried tuckling it with an idea of copying the current JVM, maybe execute the instrumented code inside it (with the exact state of the program) and come back to the original JVM when the instrumentation is done. I couldn't find a documentation on such scenario so I am wondering if there is a better approach to it.

Comment: If you want to remove the side effects of those added function calls, simply don't add them. But I'm sure that you need them executed, otherwise you wouldn't add them. And in that case, it makes no sense to execute them and then undo their effects. Could you go into detail a bit more by adding a code sample with such an instrumented function call and describe the effects? Because it seems like you shouldn't have to resort to forking a JVM to do this.

Comment: Why do you have static mutable state at all?

Comment: @LouisWasserman sorry that's was misleading I changed it to objects

Answer (score 1):

The *state* of Java program is not only the Heap. It also includes running threads, loaded classes, constant pools, caches and many other VM structures.

Saving state of a Java program is roughly the same as saving state of an arbitrary process in OS. [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) is probably the closest way to achieve this, but it's still not an easy solution.